# Entity Framework - Load only Selected properties

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have no hands on experience it EF and hence dont know the relevence of the question.

Suppose I have tables named Student (StudentId, Name, Username, Address, DOB, DeptId, NavigationProp1Id.... ) and in Department table (Deptd, DeptName., NavigationProPid). So if a table structure follows like this, when I use 'contex.Studnets ' I can get all prpoerties along with it including navigation properties and if table 2 has other navigation properties it can also be loaded. Am I correct?

If so whether it cause any performance issue? Can I load only selected properties from Entity like only UserName, Address from Student entity?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No navigation properties are not loaded immediately. They are loaded either explicitly if you use `Include` method or lazily when you access them for the first time (that is also reason why you see them in debugger = access through debugger caused lazy loading).

You can load only selected properties - it is called projection. The limitation is that you cannot load Student entity with subset of properties. You need either new class or anonymous type:

```
var query = context.Students.Select(x => new 
                {
                   x.UserName,
                   x.Address 
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Entity Framework (EF) your best solution is to query the EF context using LINQ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx). LINQ can be used to query across relationships, so in your scenario your code would look like the following:

```
var joinedlist = context.Student.Join(
                // The table we wish to join to the Student table
                context.Department,
                // Item on student table we want to join from
                studentItem => studentItem.DeptId,
                // Item on department table we want to join to
                departmentItem => departmentItem.Deptd, 
                // New object just holding the values we wish to retrieve from the joined tables
                (studentItem, departmentItem) => new {
                        StudentId = studentItem.StudentId, 
                        StudentUsername = studentItem.Username,
                        StudentAddress = studentItem.Address,
                        DepartmentName = departmentItem.DeptName, 
                        Navigation = StudentItem.NavigationProp1Id
                    }
            );
```

The above code will generate for you a queryable list, but you can do many more things with LINQ. For example selecting a subset of data and filtering your results:

```
var singleItem = joinedlist
                // Filter our joined list
                .Where(item => item.StudentId.Equals(1))
                // Select only a subset of columns
                .Select(item => new {item.StudentUsername, item.StudentAddress})
                // Return only a single item
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Regarding performance -  I would suggest getting hold of a profiler which can show you the SQL output of your LINQ statements on EF. This really helps when it comes to understanding lazy loading and where a misplaced .ToList() may be returning your entire DB!