# Web Api 2 With Entity Framework Controller return all navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to get informations from my User table with User's ID but my controller returns all of navigation properties that connected with foreign keys to other tables.

Code is simply webapi method:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        User user = db.User.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(user);
    }
```

It doesn't return only  User, it returns all navigation properties connected with this User.

How can I return only User?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076239/entity-framework-load-only-selected-properties) explains selected properties. I want all of properties, but controller returns me all of connected tables datas with foreign keys too.

Comment: Hmm, Find shouldn't load the navigation properties. Are you saying the FKs are populated or the navigation properties? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764391/entity-framework-find-method-not-working-properly

Comment: @SteveGreene thanks, I've found solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Load only Selected properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076239/entity-framework-load-only-selected-properties)

Comment: Yes, I would go with Fabio's suggestion and use a projection. Exposing your entity model in an api is dangerous.

Comment: So what is the best practice if there are so much column at table?

Comment: @FabioLuz This post explains selected properties. I want all of properties, but controller returns me all of connected tables datas with foreign keys too.

Comment: Lot's of info on the viewmodel pattern out there. Whether you choose to implement is up to you, but it definitely falls under best practices. What if you add a field later you don't want to expose to users of the api? http://wildermuth.com/2015/7/22/Mapping_Between_Entities_and_View_Models

Comment: Its good to use. Thanks @SteveGreene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for Web-Applications is to **disable the LazyLoadin** in your DbContext.

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: so you are dissident with @FabioLuz, he says it works but its not solution for this.

Comment: Actually, it's always better to return specific view model containing just the needed data. But it always up to your project if it's huge and you want to add this kind of complexity or it's simple and you want just to go with your Entities.

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay abi please accept my answer if you found it useful ;)